# Flash as3 drag and drop physics

Tags: flash, physics, gravity

In Flash cc as3 I would like to know how to fix a problem that i am having, the problem is that i am making a drag and drop game. When you drag an object it moves, when you drop it there is gravity pulling it to the ground. But I need to know how to make the object not stop in mid air, but move slightly in the x axis and then land, rather than if you throw it as hard as you can it will stop in mid air and land instead of gracefully landing...

Here is my code

```
var drag:Number = 1;

gotoAndStop(1, "Minigame-Block");

Block1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_ClickToDrag_4);

function fl_ClickToDrag_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Block1.startDrag()
    gravity = 0
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_ReleaseToDrop_4);

function fl_ReleaseToDrop_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Block1.stopDrag();
    gravity = 0.9
}

{
    var gravity = 0.9;
var floor = 711.95;
Block1.y = floor;
Block1.speedY = 0;
Block1.impulsion = 10;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterframe);
function enterframe(e:Event) {
    Block1.speedY += gravity;
    Block1.y += Block1.speedY;
    if(Block1.y > floor) {
        Block1.speedY = 0;
        Block1.y = floor

    }

}
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, space);
function space(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
        Block1.speedY = -Block1.impulsion
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a world without air resistance, the x-component of your object's velocity remains constant while the y-component changes at a constant rate due to gravity.  If the user holds the object still and drops it, it should fall vertically, but if they fling it, it should fall in a ballistic arc (a parabola).

What you want to do is record the x-component of the velocity during dragging, and then keep adding that component to the x-position for as long as it is falling.  This means implementing a MOUSE_MOVE handler which subtracts the current x position from the previous x position, divides by the number of frames elapsed since the last event, and stores it as Block1.speedX.  Then just add the line

```
Block1.y += Block1.speedY;
Block1.x += Block1.speedX;  // <--
```

You could get more elaborate with this and calculate speedX as a moving average; that would make the physics feel a little more realistic.

Comment: Please may you say where and how to add this into my code, as I am a BIG newbie!